# Touch pad not working on Linux Chromebook

Tags: linux

After a lot of trial and error I got Linux to work kn my acer chromebook 11. It’s been working fine for a few months but now when I launch Don’t starve together (one of the only games it can run) the trackpad stops working after a few minutes (approx 10). I’ve googled the question but it’s all model specific answer to Linux books that required a bios or whatnot update.

I’m not that experienced with Linux.

Thanks in advance

Comment: does the touchpad stop working within the game only? .... does an external mouse also stop working ... which Linux distribution did you install? ... what is `whatnot update`?